# LGBMClassifier + Unbalanced data + GridSearchCV()

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, lightgbm, boosting

The dependent variable is binary, the unbalanced data is 1:10, the dataset has 70k rows, the scoring is the roc curve, and I'm trying to use LGBM + GridSearchCV to get a model. However, I'm struggling with the parameters as sometimes it doesn't recognize them even when I use the parameters as the [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html) shows:

```
params = {'num_leaves': [10, 12, 14, 16],
          'max_depth': [4, 5, 6, 8, 10],
          'n_estimators': [50, 60, 70, 80],
          'is_unbalance': [True]} 

best_classifier = GridSearchCV(LGBMClassifier(), params, cv=3, scoring="roc_auc")
best_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

So:

- What is the difference between putting the parameters in the `GridsearchCV()` and `params`?
- As it's unbalanced data, I'm trying to use the `roc_curve` as the scoring metric as it's a metric that considers the unbalanced data. Should I use the argument `scoring="roc_auc"` put it in the `params` argument?

Comment: You have an extra space in `'n_estimators '` - should be `'n_estimators'`; please remedy this and edit the question so that it is not closable as "needs focus" (i.e. asking multiple questions at once).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between putting the parameters in `GridsearchCV()`or `params` is mentioned in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) of GridSearch:

When you put it in `params`:

> Dictionary with parameters names (str) as keys and lists of parameter settings to try as values, or a list of such dictionaries,
> in which case the grids spanned by each dictionary in the list are
> explored. This enables searching over any sequence of parameter
> settings.

And yes you can put the scoring also in the `params`.